# How to type square brackets in VIM with a French AZERTY keyboard?

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, macvim, neovim

I recently switched from sublime text to vim, but I have some problems with my keyboard Layout, which is a French azerty keyboard (I plan to change my keyboard).

So to type a square bracket, I must type shift+alt+5. But in vim, when I'm in INSERT mode, when I type this combination, I switch to NORMAL mode, and I can't access to my [.
So is there a way to prevent that ?
Should I remap all my keyboard ? (Or maybe there is a nice AZERTY remapping file to give an easier access to some weird French characters placement).

Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't switch to a text editor where I can't type `[`. Anyway… What OS? Terminal or GUI? If Terminal, which one? Vim OR Neovim?

Comment: On AZERTY keyboards, I've always seen `[` being accessed with AltGr+5

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `shift`+`alt`+`5` is mapped to something in your terminal, or vim(idk).
If you can use `shift`+`alt`+`5` to type a square bracket in terminal, but not vim, then it should be possible to remap it using `imap`. https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2)

If you add this to your vimrc:

```
imap <C-r> ]
imap <C-l> [
```

it will make you type "]" when you press `Ctrl`+`r`.
And "[" when you press `Ctrl`+`l`

Btw, you can map `shift`+`alt`+`5` to "[", but `shift`+`5` will go to vim as one character ("%" in QWERTY)
So I can use `imap <A-%> [` to type "[" using `shift`+`alt`+`5` in QWERTY.
I suppose you should use `imap <A-(>` in AZERTY

Comment: I would use another keybinding because `Ctrl-r` is used in insert mode to paste registers.